# how to display data in a Combobox from MySql database table and other fields in textbox - php

Tags: php, mysql, function

I am using phpMyAdmin localhost.
I have a table 
Table1: fields are

```
BatchName, BatchID, Cource, Stream,StreamCode
values: 
HS1A-2019   1   HS  Arts    1
HS1C-2019   2   HS  Commerce    3
HS1SC-2019  3   HS  Science     2
```

Now first I want to display BatchName in a Combobox. secondly, I want while selecting a BatchName from the Combobox it should display respective Course, Stream, StreamCode in textboxes. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome! Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. You are expected to try to write the code yourself. Please read [How to create a Minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), [Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already got an array of objects from the SQL query, you can then put the BatchNames into the options of a select element.
All the other information you put into textboxes and hide them using CSS.

Last but not least you write an onchange handler for your select element that will unhide the textboxes.

That's the rough overview of how to tackle this problem, as I assumed you wanted help with the general concept of how to display stuff depending on the selection of your select box using PHP. (That's not possible in PHP and HTML only, you need JS as well)

If your problem was with one of the implementations, please provide an example of what you got so far and where you ran into problems.

Comment: Thanks Sir. Sir will you help me with codes. actually i want that when page is loaded BatchName will display in the combobox and when user select a batch from the combobox it should display the respective BatchID, Cource, Stream and StreamCode in the text box. I am trying with onchange method. But it is not working.

Comment: I suggest you edit your question to provide either the full code for that part of your application or at least a stripped down example of what you tried so far.

This comment is a typical case of "I have a problem, but won't tell you what, fix it for me"  
The original question isn't a question of coding at all, but more like a task description from a business perspective that you'd give to a coder you employ or hire.